# How to pass a Func<T> without knowing the scope of T?

Tags: c#, generics

It may not be possible, but I am hoping it is!

I have a method which has scope of a generic type, and instansiates a `List<Func<GenericType>>`. I then have another method which recieves a `List<Func<T>>`. I can't have any knowledge of `T` in this method.

**Example Code**

```
public void PassFuncs<Item>()
{
  List<Func<Item>> funcs = new List<Func<Item>>();
  RecieveFuncs(funcs);
}
public void RecieveFuncs(List<Func<object>> funcs)
{
  //Do some stuff with funcs
}
```

I was wishing that it would be as easy as using `object` in place of `T` and it would be as easy of that. Of course, `T` isn't an `object`, it's a `Type` and therefore I can't interchange them. Any suggestions or is this impossible?

Comment: you can use `dynamic` instead..

Comment: Why can't you know that T exists in this scenario?

Comment: Can you make `RecieveFuncs` generic? And does it have to be a `List<T>` or is an `IEnumerable<T>` enough?

Comment: @SWeko I can't in the scope of my code, that is all. I have no need to present the scope of my code just my situation - I know at first reading it seems a bit farfetched :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your method generic:

```
public void RecieveFuncs<T>(List<Func<T>> funcs)
{
  //Do some stuff with funcs
}
```

To call it, you can either declare `T` explicitly

```
public void PassFuncs<Item>()
{
  List<Func<Item>> funcs = new List<Func<Item>>();
  RecieveFuncs<Item>(funcs);
}
```

or let the type inference magic do its work and keep the call as it is:

```
public void PassFuncs<Item>()
{
  List<Func<Item>> funcs = new List<Func<Item>>();
  RecieveFuncs(funcs);  // C# automatically infers T = Item
}
```

Comment: Please note the section in my question where I say - `I then have another method which recieves a List<Func<T>>. I can't have any knowledge of T in this method.`

Comment: @LukeHennerley: How does that contradict my answer?

Comment: Because the method signature has a generic type and therefore will have knowledge of `T`. I can't make the method generic.

Comment: @LukeHennerley: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "knowledge of `T`". My generic version of RecieveFuncs does not know that `T = Item`...

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Why can't you make the method `RecieveFuncs` generic?

Comment: @Heinzi I obviously didn't elaborate clearly enough, sorry. Daniel, it's just in the scope of my code - I surely don't have to present a reason why I am doing such thing, just the situation and problem I face?

Answer (score 3):

If you know that `Item` is a reference type, you can use variance of each function (but not of the list):

```
public void PassFuncs<Item>() where Item : class
{
    List<Func<Item>> funcs = new List<Func<Item>>();
    var tmp = funcs.ConvertAll(func => (Func<object>)func);
    RecieveFuncs(tmp);
}
```

This creates a new list, but uses the original functions. If that is not possible, you'll need to add an intermediate function:

```
public void PassFuncs<Item>()
{
    List<Func<Item>> funcs = new List<Func<Item>>();
    var tmp = funcs.ConvertAll<Func<object>>(func => () => func());
    RecieveFuncs(tmp);
}
```

Comment: +1 this works, accepted because there is an option to keep the same method signatures :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley for info, I edited to tidy the syntax a bit - but functionally 100% identical

Answer (score 3):

If you can't make `RecieveFuncs` generic for some reason, you could use:

```
public void PassFuncs<TItem>()
    where TItem:class
{
  List<Func<TItem>> funcs = new List<Func<TItem>>();
  RecieveFuncs(funcs);
}

public void RecieveFuncs(IEnumerable<Func<object>> funcs)
{
  //Do some stuff with funcs
}
```

This requires a generic constraint to reference types for `TItem`, and needs a co-variant interface like `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` on the receiving side. If you really want to receive a `List<Func<object>>` you can create a new list with `List<Func<object>>(funcs)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could "cast" the `Func<Item>` to `Func<object>`, like this

```
public delegate object Func();

public void PassFuncs<Item>()
{
  List<Func<Item>> funcs = new List<Func<Item>>();
  RecieveFuncs(funcs.Select<Func<Item>, Func<object>>(f => () => (object)f())
                    .ToList());
}

public void RecieveFuncs(List<Func<object>> funcs)
{
  //Do some stuff with funcs
}
```

This will work both for reference and value types, although it will box for the value types. If you use only reference types, use @CodesInChaos answer.